# How to write equations at centre?

Tags: equations, center

I want to bring the equation at centre of the page.

[image]

I have written the following

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq2}
x'=f(t,x), \ x(t_0)=x_0.
\end{equation}
```

I tried using `\begin{centre}` and `\end{centre}`. But it does not make any changes.

Please help me.

Comment: Please post a complete code that we can test. The default layout of `equation` is centred.

Comment: equations are centred by default in most document classes so it depends on code you have not shown

Comment: It looks like you're using the `beamer` document class. Do you by any chance load`beamer` with the option `fleqn`? And if the answer is "yes", does your code also feature the instruction `\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}`? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico Yes, I am using >\documentclass[10pt,fleqn]{beamer}. But I am not using the second one. Please advise me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(this answer makes use of supplemental information provided by the OP in a comment)

A minimal version of a test document that generates the equation layout shown in the OP's screenshot might be as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,fleqn]{beamer} 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\stepcounter{equation} % optional
\begin{equation}\label{eq2}
x'=f(t,x), \ x(t_0)=x_0.
\end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The culprit, so to say, is the option `fleqn`. `fleqn` is short for "flush-left equation". By setting this option, you're instructing LaTeX to typeset the equation -- you guessed it -- flush-left rather than centered.

The upshot? If you want the equations to be centered, do *not* specify the option `fleqn`.